# cppcheck configuration to check for freeing memory that is not owned

Tags: static-analysis, cppcheck

Is it possible to configure cppcheck to catch the following condition in C code:

```
void test1() {
    char *strp = "my string";
    flist *flistp = create_flist();
    flist_put(flistp, strp);
    destroy_flist(flistp);
}
```

What flist_put does is takes strp and transfer memory ownership to flistp (destroy_flist later takes care of freeing up that memory). In the code above, the problem is that flist_put can **not** be used, since memory is owned within test1() scope. flist_set must be used instead, which makes a copy of strp instead.

Notes - all of the following are closed-source functions:

- create_flist allocates memory for flist structure
- destroy_flist deallocates flist structure memory
- flist_put transfers memory ownership of memory pointed by passed in pointer to flist structure
- flist_set makes a copy of passed in value and adds it to flist, allocating memory for it (that flist owns)